# Needs ideas on how to insert a small text phrase above a panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border, title

I am trying to insert the "Puzzle Game" text circled in red in the attached image.

I have already placed the 4 blue buttons and the textfields all in 1 GridLayout.

I tried inserting the text together with the GridLayout as a non-clickable button, but it didn't work as the sizes per cell in GridLayout is the same throughout.

Trying to use setBounds as well, but it doesn't even show up in the JFrame =/ .

[image]

```
    // create a new panel - panel1
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();   
    // set layout of panel1
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,200));

    // create new buttons - button1 to button4
    JButton button1  = new JButton("Start Game");
    JButton button2  = new JButton("Get History");
    JButton button3  = new JButton("Reset Game");
    JButton button4  = new JButton("Exit Game");

    // create label and text field for entering of player's names 
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter Player's name:",JLabel.CENTER);
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField();

    // add the labels and text field to panel1
    panel1.add(label1);
    panel1.add(field1);

    // adds button1 to button4 to panel1
    panel1.add(button1);
    panel1.add(button2);
    panel1.add(button3);
    panel1.add(button4);

    // create a new general panel to contain all panels containing components placed at the bottom
    JPanel btmGenP = new JPanel();
    this.add(btmGenP,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    btmGenP.add(panel1,FlowLayout.LEFT);

    // create a new panel - panel2
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(null);
        panel2.setBounds(50,50,50,50);
        this.add(panel2);     

    // add Jlabel text to panel2
    JLabel puzgame = new JLabel("~~Puzzle Game~~");
    panel2.add(puzgame);
```

Comment: btw: [don't use setXXSize](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657), ever

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("~~Puzzle Game~~"));
```

Comment: Thanks a great deal. Spot on answer =)